# Incorrect position of blocks on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make an adaptive design for the http://bodymaker.kz/.
The problem is that on the iPhone the blocks overlap each other like this:

[image]

It looks like a problem with the height of the blocks, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please post some code to help others assist you. Visit the following link for more information: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)